# Mysql, select many rows and assign different values to each row transactionally

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MySQL 8 table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `segment_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The table is populated with some random values

```
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `test_codes` (`segment_id`) VALUES ('1');
```

My applications has the following task: A request comes with an array of codes eg [1,200,10,18] and I need to get 4 rows (equal to array size) from the database where the code = 0 and update the code_id at each row with the values 1,200, 10, 18 transitionally.

A concurrent request that wants to update the code from another running thread, should not access the selected rows of the first thread.

How can I do this?

After the update the first selected row will have code_id 1, the second selected row code_id 200, the third 10 and the last one 18. In other words the task must find rows with unassigned codes (code_id=0) and set a value to each row.

Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60e555/1

Comment: So how might the table look afterwards?

Comment: Its not clear if you want the update `code_id` to `1,200, 10, 18` or you want to update the first row you select to `code_id` to `1` and the second to `200` etc

Comment: Please provide definite sample data (fill all columns) in the question, and add desired result for this data and provided criteria (input array).

Comment: updated my question, each selected row will have a new code_id.

Comment: I think he want to update the rows that has code = 0 with the numbers he got from request array. like the first row that has code = 0 value should be updated with 1 ,second with 200 and so on..

Comment: I assume the too @kelvin but assumtion is the mother of all ^%$£$%

Comment: What language is your Application written in

Comment: It is written in cpp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single statement which you may build in the app

```
update test_codes
join
(
  select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn
  from test_codes
  where code_id = 0
) t on t.id = test_codes.id
join ( 
 -- a table of new values with their positions
 select 1 rn, 1 val union all
 select 2, 200 union all
 select 3, 10 union all
 select 4, 18
) v on v.rn = t.rn
set code_id = v.val
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22038456ac2be1fcd1c11f5f245e1658)

Comment: What are the number 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @malefstro, Those numbers are positions you want to place values at. I.e. 200 must take pos 2. They are supposed to be created by the app.

Comment: OK I got you, these are just numbers starting from 1 and ending to the size of the array. they are not column ids

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support arrays.  I would suggest that you first load the array into a table.  This is just a convenience, but it is handy.

Then you can use a complex `update` with `join` to handle this:

```
update test_codes tc join
       (select tc2.*,
               row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
        from test_codes tc2
       ) tc2
       on tc2.id = tc.id join
       (select nc.*,
               row_number() over (order by code_id) as seqnum
        from new_codes nc
       ) nc
       on tc2.seqnum = nc.seqnum
    set tc.code_id = nc.code_id;
```

EDIT:

You can construct the query directly from the codes:

```
update test_codes tc join
       (select tc2.*,
               row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
        from test_codes tc2
       ) tc2
       on tc2.id = tc.id join
       (select ? as code, 1 as seqnum union all
        select ? as code, 2 union all
        . . .
       ) nc
       on tc2.seqnum = nc.seqnum
    set tc.code_id = nc.code_id;
```

Comment: I don't have the option of the second table.

Comment: @malefstro . . . You can construct the table on the fly.  I edited the answer to show how.